# RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding with DECRYPT_MODE

Tags: encryption, hash, rsa, sha1, pkcs#1

I am trying to decrypt a string with public key to compare with a hash. The code is the followig

```
byte[] dectyptedText = null;
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);
return dectyptedText;
```

The above code generates a string like this (base64encode)

`MCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQUy3qkZYgfRVo2Sv1F9bHa3pDs044=`

The hash is generated by the following code

```
 byte[] key = stringToHash.getBytes();
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
 hash = md.digest(key);
```

The above code generates a sample hash like the following

`y3qkZYgfRVo2Sv1F9bHa3pDs044=`

If you notice both has the correct hash which is `y3qkZYgfRVo2Sv1F9bHa3pDs044=`

But the decrypt code generates and prepends an extra `MCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQU`

Dont understand how this extra thing is added and why.

Can please somebody throw some light on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `Cipher` to create or verify signatures. Instead you should use `Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA")`.

Signature schemes and encryption schemes are different and they are not necessarily compatible with each other. For starters, they use different padding methods, and these padding methods are part of the security of the algorithm.

Even if you can get signature verification to work using Cipher, the chances are that you haven't verified the signature to the full extend, and your home-brewed signature verification scheme may (and possibly will) fail if a different implementation of `Cipher` is being used.

The code in the question seems to be using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption rather than for signature generation, so it is probably not correct.

Comment: got it. thanks owlstead. this was a non standard signature section. I will try to standardize it using Signature class.

Answer (score 7):

That's the PKCS1 Padding.
The algorithm appends the pkcs padding to your clear text data (i.e. your hash) to prevent some attacks based on repeated encrypted plain text data. It's a way to randomize the input data. If you re-encrypt the very same hash using the same key you'll get different pkcs header data (and a different cypher block of course). Obviously the pkcs padding has a fixed length so you can strip it out to get your original plain text.

Comment: thanks g_g. it was the digestinfo padding (alog info) 20 bytes or so.

Comment: i tried, but it seems I need a reputation of 15+ to do it :( ...i will do it once i get that